# Использование std::iterator и std::unique_ptr с методами std::copy и std::memcpy

Tags: c++, c++14, итераторы, unique-ptr

В функцию передаётся итератор и количество байт, которое необходимо скопировать в динамический массив к которому есть доступ через unique_ptr. Как мне правильно произвести вызов std::copy и std::memcpy в этом случае?

```
void Foo(std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, uint8_t> iter, int32_t length) {
    unique_ptr<char[]> container = make_unique<char[]>(100);
    std::copy (iter, iter + length, container); // Как скопировать содержимое iter в container
    std::memcpy (container, iter , length); // Как скопировать содержимое iter в container
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) cout << container[i];
};
```

Comment: Шаблон `std::iterator` не имеет никакого отношения к тому, как вы его пытаетесь использовать в этом коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ для такого кода - никак.

Дело в том, что `std::iterator` - просто предоставляет псевдонимы `iterator_category`, `value_type`, `difference_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, причем обязательно передать только первые два параметра для определения `iterator_category` и `value_type`, остальные псевдонимы для типов будут сделаны на их основе, конечно, если Вам они подойдут. `std::iterator` не предоставляет никакого функционала, т.е. ни `operator*`, ни `operator++`, и т.д. у него нет, поэтому использовать его так, как Вы хотите не получится.

Его можно использовать, например, для реализации своего итератора:

```
class MyIterator: 
    public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, MyType>
//Наследуемся от std::iterator с нужными аргументами,
//чтобы псевдонимы сами сгенерировались.
```

Стоит заметить, что `std::iterator`, начиная с `C++17` является устаревшим.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я могу как-то передать произвольный итератор в функцию и использовать его там? Произвольный в смысле не важно, что это будет за итератор, массива или например вектора.

Comment: @mrFieldy Обычно это `template<typename Itr> void foo(Itr begin, Itr end);`.